# WSO2 EMM mysql database setup

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I am using WSO2 EMM 1.1.0. The documents talk about using a MySQL instead of H2 https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Setting+up+MySQL. It talks about editing the master-datasource.xml file and updating the  WSO2_CARBON_DB, WSO2_EMM_DB and WSO2AM_DB  databases. It then gives steps on priming those db's. But the master-datasource.xml file also contains the WSO2_IDENTITY_DB, SOCIAL_CACHE, SOCIAL_CASSANDRA_DB and JAGH2. I expect all of those can be moved to MySQL as well but I don't see the database scripts to set them up. What is the proper procedures to set up a system that uses MySQL instead of H2? Not to mention that the emm database had the database name hard coded into the setup script "USE WSO2EMM_DB" thus nullifying the master-datasource.xml file.

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in this documentation[1] under the topic 'How to migrate from H2 to MySQL'

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release

Comment: But what about the other databases listed in the master-datasource.xml? Are they even used in a EMM setup?

Comment: Yes, they are necessary for store other info, such as carbondb stores information related to carbon server and migrating them to mysql is mentioned in the same doc i have shared above

Comment: I don't see any direct mention of these database in that document: WSO2_IDENTITY_DB, SOCIAL_CACHE, SOCIAL_CASSANDRA_DB and JAGH2. So how can they be set up my MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure WSO2EMM_DB, WSO2AM_DB and WSO2CARBON_DB and WSO2IDENTITY_DB if you are going ahead with a larger deployment. H2 is setup just for make the out of the box experience better. You can create those DBs, Configure master_datasources.xml properly for all above DBs. And then run the server with the flag -Dsetup. It will get the configurations done automatically.

If it fails, you can also go to SERVER_HOME/dbscripts folder and find all the scripts for all above databases. Run them separately and run the server in the usual way which mentioned in our documentation.